# File Transfer to Raspberry Pi using Atom Electron (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, raspberry-pi, electron, atom-editor

I'm trying to set up an Electron (NODE JS) Application that can connect to a Raspberry Pi on the network via (SSH or SCP) and wirelessly transfer files from the PC/MAC/LINUX to a certain directory on the Raspbery Pi!

I know there will have to be some way to locate the raspberry pi I am looking for on the network first.

Any pointers on how the best way to go about this for cross-platform compatibility would be awesome!

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Look at advertising over - and listening to - [mDNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS) (ZeroConf).

I've used [the `mdns` node module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mdns) to great effect before.

Answer (score -1):

Is [this](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-Pi-Finder) what you're looking for? If not, it's a good start. It's written in Electron and nodejs, and has ssh capabilities.

Context:

This electron app finds your Pi if you're connected on the same network, and has the capability to upload files, run commands in its own native terminal, and configure wifi. If you're looking for hints on how to do file transfer with Node and electron, this is a great start.